# How to tell admob if I uploaded my app in playstore?

Tags: android, admob

I developed an android app and monetized it with Admob(though real ads are not showing yet). When I generated Ad unit id in Admob, that time I selected "not uploaded on app store" so if with same Ids I upload on app store how to connect to admob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to your admob console and from `Apps` select the app you created there.
- then from the left panel select `App Settings`.
- You can see `App name & store link` where you can add your playstore app.

Comment: ok so i just developed an app. test ads were showing so i remove addTestDevice() from code and generated a signed apk. so when will it start showing real ads on my app. Is there any requirement e.g minimum installs on devices, or time or if only 2 devices use that app so will it show ad on those 2 devices or not –

Comment: did you checked `containds Ads` in the playstore? It will take about a day for the ads to start showing.

Comment: no i didn't upload on app store yet. is it necessary for adds to upload? if not then how many days and devices it normally takes to show first ad for apps not in app store

Comment: I don't have much experience in admob but you can test and compare the results.

Answer (score 2):

Goto AdMob Console

Select your app from the list and **GoTo App Settings**

And Follow the below steps

[image]

Click on Edit, follow screen will display

Click on Link your app with google play
Enter your app ID in next Dialog

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok so i just developed an app. test ads were showing so i remove addTestDevice() from code and generated a signed apk. so when will it start showing real ads on my app. Is there any requirement e.g minimum installs on devices, or time or if only 2 devices use that app so will it show ad on those 2 devices or not

Comment: There is no any limit. Make sure you generate test id from your account, not using google test ids.

Comment: i didn't upload on app store yet. is it necessary for adds to upload? if not then how many days and devices it normally takes to show first ad for apps not in app store

Comment: No it is not necessary to upload in playstore. If you build app for release, you can view ads immediately.